# Setting up a static IP address: two wifi modems, one static and one DHCP

Tags: wireless-networking

my modem sometimes has problems with DHCP giving constant "IP conflicts".So I decided to set static IPs for each of my computers and phones. The problem is, with this IP,  the computers don't connect to a second wifi modem which has a different IP requirement. What do I do for this to work?  I wanna have static IPs for this modem and DHCP set for the second modem

Comment: I'd look at sorting out why DHCP isn't working properly across your entire network before investigating other solutions. Can you provide a diagram of your current network that isn't working for you? You say "two wifi modems" - do you mean you have two wifi modem/routers and you've connected them together and your LAN no longer works properly? Without knowing your topology it's hard for us to provide a solution.

Comment: @Kinnectus - Thank you for your fast response. No, I have two modems, each connected to a different phone line. Both have internet connections.

Comment: Ah, so you have two ISP providing simultaneous Internet... for this to work "properly" and be able to use both Internets at the same time you'd need to look for a dual-WAN router or see if an open-course router firmware can do dual-WAN capability and reconfigure two router ports to be WAN ports. personally, I'd look for a proper solution to ue both at the same time - DrayTek offer dual-WAN routers but they might be a budget breaker... Something like this: https://www.abptech.com/old/blog/wp-content/uploads/draytek-dual-wan-2.png

Comment: Did you read my explanations at all?  @kinnectus

Comment: So you want to have the ability to have "static" IPs for your devices (wifi) for when connected to one wifi network, but then have DHCP addresses when connected to the other wifi network? Unless your devices support different profiles for different wifi networks (or whether a DHCP server is available) then you're going to have to live with manually changing the settings for each connection to the different networks. Windows: "Alternate Configuration" in the TCP/IP settings for the NIC.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do and thanks for the reply again. Would you please elaborate more?